# Footnoterule comes wrong if box exceeds a page

Tags: footnotes, page-breaking

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem}%
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[framed,final]{mcode}
\usepackage{xcolor,textcomp}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\noindent\hspace*{-24\p@}\uwave{\hspace{138\p@}}\par\removelastskip\nointerlineskip\vskip5.65pt\nointerlineskip}%
\lstnewenvironment{ssmallpython}[1][]{%
\lstset{%
language=python,%
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,%
otherkeywords={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9 , 0, -, =, +, [, ], (, ), \{, \}, :, *, !},%
keywordstyle=\color{blue},%
stringstyle=\color{red},%
showstringspaces=false,%
emph={class, pass, in, for, while, if, is, elif, else, not, and, or,%
def, print, exec, break, continue, return},%
emphstyle=\color{black}\bfseries,%
emph={[2]True, False, None, self},%
emphstyle=[2]\color{black!10},%
emph={[3]from, import, as},%
emphstyle=[3]\color{blue},%
upquote=true,%
mathescape=false,%
morecomment=[s]{"""}{"""},%
commentstyle=\color{gray}\slshape,%
aboveskip=12pt,belowskip=12pt,xleftmargin=-2pt,xrightmargin=3pt,framexleftmargin=20pt,framextopmargin=1pt,%
rulesepcolor=\color{gray},#1%
}}{}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is for test. 
While the above imaging data set has been downloaded in advance due to its
size, it is also possible to access the SDSS Data Archive Server directly and in real time.
In astroML.datasets, the function fetch\_sdss\_spectrum
provides an
\index{data set tools!fetch\_sdss\_spectrum}
interface to the FITS (Flexible Image Transport System; a standard file format in
astronomy for manipulating images and tables\footnote{See http://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/iaufwg/iaufwg.html})
files located on the SDSS spectral server.  This operation is done
in the background using the built-in python module urllib2.
\index{software packages!urllib2}
 For details on how this is accomplished, see the source code of
fetch\_sdss\_spectrum.

This is for test. 
While the above imaging data set has been downloaded in advance due to its
size, it is also possible to access the SDSS Data Archive Server directly and in real time.
In astroML.datasets, the function fetch\_sdss\_spectrum
provides an
\index{data set tools!fetch\_sdss\_spectrum}
interface to the FITS (Flexible Image Transport System; a standard file format in
astronomy for manipulating images and tables\footnote{See http://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/iaufwg/iaufwg.html})
files located on the SDSS spectral server.  This operation is done
in the background using the built-in python module urllib2.
\index{software packages!urllib2}
 For details on how this is accomplished, see the source code of
fetch\_sdss\_spectrum.

This is for test. 
While the above imaging data set has been downloaded in advance due to its
size, it is also possible to access the SDSS Data Archive Server directly and in real time.
In astroML.datasets, the function fetch\_sdss\_spectrum
provides an
\index{data set tools!fetch\_sdss\_spectrum}
interface to the FITS (Flexible Image Transport System; a standard file format in
astronomy for manipulating images and tables\footnote{See http://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/iaufwg/iaufwg.html})
files located on the SDSS spectral server.  This operation is done
in the background using the built-in python module urllib2.
\index{software packages!urllib2}
 For details on how this is accomplished, see the source code of
fetch\_sdss\_spectrum.

This is for test. 
While the above imaging data set has been downloaded in advance due to its
size, it is also possible to access the SDSS Data Archive Server directly and in real time.
In astroML.datasets, the function fetch\_sdss\_spectrum
provides an
\index{data set tools!fetch\_sdss\_spectrum}
interface to the FITS (Flexible Image Transport System; a standard file format in
astronomy for manipulating images and tables\footnote{See http://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/iaufwg/iaufwg.html})
files located on the SDSS spectral server.  This operation is done
in the background using the built-in python module urllib2.
\index{software packages!urllib2}
 For details on how this is accomplished, see the source code of
fetch\_sdss\_spectrum.

\begin{ssmallpython}
In [1]: %pylab
Using matplotlib backend: TkAgg
Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib

In [2]: from astroML.datasets import fetch_sdss_spectrum
In [3]: plate = 1615  # plate number of the spectrum
In [4]: mjd = 53166  # modified Julian date
In [5]: fiber = 513  # fiber ID on a given plate
In [6]: data = fetch_sdss_spectrum(plate, mjd, fiber)
In [7]: ax = plt.axes()
In [8]: ax.plot(data.wavelength(), data.spectrum, '-k')
In [9]: ax.set_xlabel(r'$\lambda (\AA)$')
In [10]: ax.set_ylabel('Flux')
\end{ssmallpython}

\end{document}
```

And the output was:

[image]

If the box exceeds page to page, then some unwanted vertical rules are coming in both left and right side of the footnote (which are marked in red color). Please suggest that how can I fix this...

Comment: use tcolorbox instead of framed.

Comment: I'm getting `! LaTeX Error: File \`mcode.sty' not found.` with this.

Comment: @Skillmon You can get the file from https://github.com/nasa/nasa-latex-docs/blob/master/support/packages/mcode/mcode.sty

Comment: @Skillmon Sorry to disturb you, is there any suggestion for my requirement?

Comment: You could use `mdframed` around the verbatim environment and drop the usage of the `framed` option to `mcode`.

Comment: @Skillmon thanks and will check ...